# Ruby mechanize doesn't get the full content

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I'm using Mechanize and Nokogiri to parse some lotto results from these two sites (they're very similar):
http://www1.caixa.gov.br/loterias/loterias/lotofacil/lotofacil_resultado.asp
http://lotofacil.resultadoloteria.org/

Here's my code:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new
agent.user_agent_alias = 'Mac Safari'
page = agent.get('http://lotofacil.resultadoloteria.org/')
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(page.body)
doc.xpath('//table[@class="tabela_jogo"]//span').each { |value| puts value }
```

The second site works fine. Result:

```
<span id="lfacil1">01</span>
<span id="lfacil2">03</span>
<span id="lfacil3">05</span>
<span id="lfacil4">08</span>
<span id="lfacil5">10</span>
<span id="lfacil6">11</span>
<span id="lfacil7">13</span>
<span id="lfacil8">14</span>
<span id="lfacil9">15</span>
<span id="lfacil10">18</span>
<span id="lfacil11">20</span>
<span id="lfacil12">22</span>
<span id="lfacil13">23</span>
<span id="lfacil14">24</span>
<span id="lfacil15">25</span>
```

But I can't get the lotto numbers from the first. Here's the result:

```
<span id="lfacil1"></span>
<span id="lfacil2"></span>
<span id="lfacil3"></span>
<span id="lfacil4"></span>
<span id="lfacil5"></span>
<span id="lfacil6"></span>
<span id="lfacil7"></span>
<span id="lfacil8"></span>
<span id="lfacil9"></span>
<span id="lfacil10"></span>
<span id="lfacil11"></span>
<span id="lfacil12"></span>
<span id="lfacil13"></span>
<span id="lfacil14"></span>
<span id="lfacil15"></span>
<span id="lfacil1_2"></span>
<span id="lfacil2_2"></span>
<span id="lfacil3_2"></span>
<span id="lfacil4_2"></span>
<span id="lfacil5_2"></span>
<span id="lfacil6_2"></span>
<span id="lfacil7_2"></span>
<span id="lfacil8_2"></span>
<span id="lfacil9_2"></span>
<span id="lfacil10_2"></span>
<span id="lfacil11_2"></span>
<span id="lfacil12_2"></span>
<span id="lfacil13_2"></span>
<span id="lfacil14_2"></span>
<span id="lfacil15_2"></span>
```

I think is something with Mechanize, because `p page.body` returns the content without the lotto numbers too. Any ideas?

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because they aren't there. I found them for you though:

```
page = agent.get('http://www1.caixa.gov.br/loterias/loterias/lotofacil/lotofacil_pesquisa_new.asp')
numbers = page.body.split('|')[3..17]
```

also instead of this:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(page.body)
```

mechanize has already taken care of that for you:

```
doc = page.parser
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But how did you find that page?

Comment: You're welcome. I loaded it in chrome with charles proxy open and then searched charles for the numbers.